# How to change user email in PHP Firebase using CORE PHP not any framework

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a project where I need to update the user email in firebase. I'm using core PHP for that as it is the requirement of the project.

I'm following the official [documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-management.html#change-a-user-s-email) and I'm able to delete the user successfully but when it comes to updating the email of the user I'm unable to do that. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Following is the code snippet:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_post['update_user'])){
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $updateData = [
            'email' => $email,
        ];
        $updatequery_result = $auth->changeUserEmail($user_id,$updateData);

        if($updatequery_result){
            header('Location:manage_user.php');
        }
        else{
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

Please note that the user email and user id are coming from an input field. So both email and id are being received on the current page.

Comment: Nothing against the documentation or library you're using, but I hope you're aware that those are not maintained by Firebase (which is what I assume you mean by "official"). They're from a third-party developer, built on top of Firebase's (official) REST APIs.

Comment: "I'm unable to do that" Why are you unable? Does the code not work? Is there an error? If so, what was the exact error message? If now, how did you determine it didn't work?

Comment: The linked library is indeed NOT an official Firebase Admin SDK - I should know, I'm it's maintainer ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
$updatequery_result = $auth->changeUserEmail($user_id,$updateData['email']);
```

Answer (score 1):

**This will work**

```
<?php
        if(isset($_post['update_user'])){
            $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];

            $updatequery_result = $auth->changeUserEmail($user_id,$email);
    
            if($updatequery_result){
                header('Location:manage_user.php');
            }
            else{
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
        }
    ?>
```

**Don't  take it in array **
No need of this code

```
  $updateData = [
                'email' => $email,
            ];
```